# Getting Wordpress REST-API content data inside a plugin with embed data

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating my own routes for the wodpress api. At some point I need the rest content of the post and pages, to do this i have this function:

```
function get_rest_content($id, $type)
{
    if ($id > 0) {
        $request = new WP_REST_Request('GET', '/wp/v2/'.$type.'/' . $id);
        $response = rest_do_request($request)->data;
    } else {
        $response = null;
    }


    if (empty($response)) {
        return new WP_Error('wpse-error',
            esc_html__('No '.$type. 'found', 'wpse'),
            ['status' => 404]);
    }
    return $response;
}

$post_1 = get_rest_content(1,'posts') // give me the rest content of the post with id=1
```

but if I want to have the post content with embed data I change:

```
new WP_REST_Request('GET', '/wp/v2/'.$type.'/' . $id);
```

to

```
new WP_REST_Request('GET', '/wp/v2/'.$type.'/' . $id . '?_embed=true');
```

but this new request returns **rest_no_route** error

Comment: Your request with embed seems correct to me. On my installation "http://me.local.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/296?_embed=true" works. Try entering the equivalent for your type and id in your browser. What response do you get?

Comment: @user8262086, if I use the address manually on the browser this works as I spect but in this code no, maybe something fail with the `WP_REST_Request` I also try with WP_REST_Request::from_url as the documentation say and give me the same error

Comment: When get_rest_content is called have your rest routes already been registered?

Comment: @user8262086 I update my question with my routes and callbacks

Comment: As an experiment can you try "new WP_REST_Request('GET', '/wp/v2/posts/999?_embed=true');" where 999 is a valid post id on your system. I am trying to find out if the problem is specific to your route or your code so I want to run your code on a known good route.

Comment: not working for new `WP_REST_Request('GET', '/wp/v2/posts/1?_embed=true')` but working for `WP_REST_Request('GET', '/wp/v2/posts/1')` i think that is a bug or something in the WP_REST_Request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read the source code and now understand. The second parameter of new WP_REST_Request() is the route only without query parameters. The query parameters are specified in another method. E.g.,

```
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', 'wp/v2/posts/999' );
$request->set_query_params( [ '_embed' => '1' ] );
```

However, this will not work as '_embed' is a special query parameter. It is not handled by WP_REST_Server::dispatch(), which means rest_do_request() will not handle '_embed' as rest_do_request() is just a wrapper of WP_REST_Server::dispatch().

The reason '_embed' works from a URL is that URLs are processed by WP_REST_Server::serve_request() which calls WP_REST_Server::dispatch() but also calls WP_REST_Server::response_to_data() which calls WP_REST_Server::embed_links().

If you want '_embed' to work in your get_rest_content() you will need to add the code for WP_REST_Server::embed_links().

Answer (score 0):

I found a Github issue but the workaround is not working for me (at least for my code+WordPress version): https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2857

Did you try adding the embeddable links to the response?

```
//get the post
$response = rest_do_request($request)->get_data();

//add the embeddable links 
$results_with_embed = rest_ensure_response(rest_get_server()->response_to_data( $response, true ));
```